# SCM-Manager where is the application

Tags: server, scmmanager

I am trying to understand how scm-manager (i'm running 1.60) works.

I work on a local network of many computers. I can connect to http//localhost:8080/scm from within the computer that has scm-manager

Or i can replace local host with the name of this computer and connect from other computers in the network.

the reason i'm confused is because I assume there must be some sort of server that listens on 8080 on this computer, but when I look through windows processes I don't see any jetty server. I don't see any scm-server process running on the computer.

Can you explain where the scm-manager server lives?

I looked in IIS and I don't see it anywhere there either.

very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find a Java process somewhere, like the one in the image. This is the case for nearly all Java based programs. You can distinguish them when you take a look at the (most times very long) parameters list. For SCM-Manager, you will find jetty there, for example.

[Image of windows task manager with Java process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXTxu.png)

Comment: Thank you so much Rene!!

Comment: also the reason i was having such a tough time is that it was being run by a "service account" at the organization which I was unaware of -> i had to filter processes to show all users to figure it out! very tricky since no user I was aware fo was logged in -